# User form closes when a different workbook is closed

Tags: excel, vba

Kindly assist on the code that I can use to prevent different closing workbook affecting a user forms of another workbook from closing. I have three user forms. Userform1, Userform2 and userform3. I want all these user forms not to be affected by closing the workbook. This is the code I am using:

```
Sub Auto_Close()
    If This Workbook.Saved = False Then
        This Workbook.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what is `This Workbook` with a space between the words, you mean `ThisWorkbook` one word ? why are you not using the Workbook events ? put your code in `Workbook_BeforeClose` event

Comment: @ShaiRado, sorry its a mistake i made, it should be ThisWorkbook. and it has a name "test"

Comment: i would appreciate if you write the code please, i am a beginner in programming

Comment: `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` in your workbook code, not `Sub Auto_Close()` in your module.

Comment: Best way to select that sub would not be to type it in as I did for you. Open your workbook code, for your left tab (Where by default it says (General)), select `Workbook`. On your declarations tab (the right side) select `BeforeClose`. It will make the blank sub for you with the proper statement. [It should look like this.](http://puu.sh/r4hd3/ec4eb6b246.png)

Comment: do you mean this 'Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub'

Comment: Yes, try that and tell us if it fixes your problem. Make sure you're putting that in the workbook's code that you're closing.

Comment: no, all i want is any workbook being closed should not make my user forms to close, because the user forms are in a different workbook

Comment: the problem is not fixed yet

Comment: How would you have a user form prompt and then close an archive? UserForm comes first, Excel shouldn't let you close archives until userform is solved

Comment: You're going to have to show more of your code, including which workbooks the code is in and which workbook is getting closed. I typed in what I told you to do on my own 2 excel files, and the userform persists even after the second workbook is closed.

Comment: If you're trying to test this by running the code in your vba viewer, it may not work. You should run the code that shows your userform.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as the answer with a picture for you to reference. Your userform should be in the project that stays open. The picture spells it out pretty clearly.

[image]

If your issue persists, make your userform modeless. You can do this by adding this: `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`. Or you can set your userform property `ShowModal = False`.

Comment: i guess you didnt get me right. it is not just one workbook affecting this. It is more that one workbook causing this. there is no relation between the many workbooks and the specific workbook that has my code and User forms. If a workbook out of the "many" different workbooks is closed  and i  also had user form (either userform1, userform2 or userform3) that was open, the closing workbook makes the user form to close too.

Comment: I'm not sure how my solution doesn't apply to what you're saying... As long as you don't close the workbook your vba project is part of, you won't close the userform. Did you try my answer? Do you have updated code that still isn't working? How are you closing the workbook? Did you set your userform to modeless?

Comment: Tyeler, i did set all my three user forms property 'ShowModal = False' but not helping. Just for you to know i am not closing the workbook that has the user forms nor am i closing the user forms either. the excel books i intend to close have no relation tho the excel book having my code (its totally a different excel book(s) and it has no code.)

Comment: remember my workbook is always hidden. so i am only showing userforms when opening it. it is only one userform that has a command button to make the workbook visible. so if i am on the userforms (that is with my workbook hidden) then i have other excel workbooks also open then close them, it also closes the userforms. so this problem happens because workbook is hedden

Comment: what version of excel are you using?

Comment: i am using office 2013

Comment: Can you show the parts of your code affecting all this? I don't know how else to help you. There isn't a lot to this, and if my answer isn't fixing it then I'll need more information to go by.

Comment: i wish i knew how to upload the excel template for you to check

Comment: you can't copy and paste the code to your question? Click `Edit` at the bottom left of your original question and put it up there